# Use <use> within <clipPath> in <defs>

Tags: svg

Can I use `<use>` to refer to a previously declared object inside a `<clipPath>` declaration?
So that it uses that element as definition for the clip path?

For example:

```html
<defs>
    <rect id="foo" width="20" height="20" />
    <clipPath id="bar">
        <use href="#foo" />
    </clipPath>
</defs>
```

Comment: Isn't this pretty straightforward to verify? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried it numerous times in a different context, where the `rect` was surrounded by a `g` which had the `id`. I have to admit that I never tried the straightforward example in the post.

Comment: So the answer you're really looking for is that a <use> element in a clipPath must point directly to a shape. And the question you meant to ask was why doesn't this clipPath that points to a <g> work?

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, but that would be another question. I will leave this question up since it might help people. It seems like svg does not support `g` objects inside `clipPath`s at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `<use>` command inside the `clipPath` declaration to refer to any external objects inside the svg file. 
In the example below, clipPath cuts a `80 x 80px` square from the image.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid red">
<defs>
    <rect id="foo" width="80" height="80" />
    <clipPath id="bar">
        <use href="#foo" />
    </clipPath>
</defs> 

<image clip-path="url(#bar)" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1" x="20" y="20" height="100%" width="100%" />
</svg>
```

The red square shows the border of the entire canvas svg.